# Prove that if $\mathcal{N}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{N}(B)$ then $\mathcal{R}(B^\intercal) \subseteq \mathcal{R}(A^\intercal)$

Tags: linear-algebra

It was asked to prove the following statement:

$\mathcal{N}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{N}(B) \rightarrow \mathcal{R}(B^\intercal) \subseteq \mathcal{R}(A^\intercal)$

For me, it is intuitively true (somewhat because of the rank theorem), and I want to prove by contradiction. So I am supposing a $z \in \mathcal{R}(B), \not\in \mathcal{R}(A)$, but I can't go on beyond this. I am always rounding the fact that $z$ is a linear combination of the rows of $B$, that the null space and the row space are both founded in the echelon form (though the former is related to the *reduced* echelon form), but that is it. What additional properties must $z$ have so we can get a contradiction?

EDIT: $\mathcal{N}$ stands for null space of a matrix whereas $\mathcal{R}$ stands for range of a matrix.

Comment: What $\mathcal N$ and $\mathcal R$ denote, if you don't mind?

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, my mistake. I edited the question and added the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

$\because \mathcal{N}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{N}(B)$

$\Rightarrow \mathcal{N}(A) = \mathcal{N}\begin{bmatrix}
A\\
B\end{bmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow Rank(A)=Rank\begin{bmatrix}
A\\
B\end{bmatrix}\ \ \text{(Using  Rank-Nullity Theorem)}$

$\Rightarrow RowSpace(B)\subseteq RowSpace(A) $

$\Rightarrow ColumnSpace(B^T)\subseteq ColumnSpace(A^T) $

$\Rightarrow \mathcal{R}(B^T) \subseteq \mathcal{R}(A^T)$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is the meaning of the first step. Can you elaborate?

Comment: the null space of $A$ is the same as the null space of the matrix obtained by putting the matrix $B$ right below the matrix $A$ (call it $C$). That is to say, if a vector gets mapped to the zero vector by $A$ then it must get mapped to the zero vector by $C$ as well. Conversely, if $C$ maps a vector to the zero vector, then $A$ must also map that vector similarly.